# How can I increase the size of (icons) thumbnails when opening files to upload in browsers?

Tags: macos, browser, icons, finder, thumbnails

This is the view I get when I want to upload a file to OS X' browser. I like the thumbnail view, but as you can see, they are too small.

[image]

I don't mind showing fewer pictures – I just want a bigger thumbnail view.

How can I change that?

Answer (score 1):

Right click inside the window & select 'Show View options' or  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>J</kbd>

The icon size is adjustable from there.
You can also set it to show icon previews.

[image]

Comment: Yes, it works in finder, but doesn't in browser, there I cant open this options ((((

Comment: "You can also set it to show icon previews."  - yes, I use it, but it is not convenient When I need to upload a large number of images and choose them from folder with even more images

Answer (score 1):

I found it, must change file `.../user/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist`

`FK_DefaultIconViewSettings` -> `iconSize`

[image: Screenshot]